# USING DATEADD but no data export to target de

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, sql

```
SELECT A.ContactKey, A.Name, A.Email, A.Phone
FROM customerfield as A
    INNER JOIN orderfield as B ON (A.ContactKey = B.ContactKey)
WHERE PurchaseDate <= DATEADD (DAY,-7, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
    AND PurchaseItem = 'Shoes'
    AND Quantity >= 1
```

I want to export DE who buys Shoes last 7 days.
But when I run this query in automation studio, the process going success
however there's no data in target DE.

Anyone knows what is going wrong for query?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few potential issues with the query:

It appears that the table names may be incorrect. The query references "customerfield" and "orderfield," but it's unclear if those are the actual names of the Data Extensions.

You have not provided the structure of your Data Extensions, so I assume the fields used in the WHERE statement are from the second table, thus I added prefixes for the second table.

With these issues in mind, here's a revised version of the query:

```
SELECT A.ContactKey, A.Name, A.Email, A.Phone
FROM customerfield as A
    INNER JOIN orderfield as B ON (A.ContactKey = B.ContactKey)
WHERE b.PurchaseDate <= DATEADD (DAY,-7, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
    AND b.PurchaseItem = 'Shoes'
    AND b.Quantity >= 1
```

Note that I've made some assumptions about the actual table and column names, so you may need to adjust those to match your DE schema.